# Create img or iso on android

Tags: android, iso

I would know if there is a way on android to create an iso or img file from a directory.  I want to do this programmatically. Thank you so much.

Comment: you can **zip** files.

Comment: Hi thank you for answer. I don't need to zip. I want to make an iso or img file because I want to mount it in a virtual usb like DriveDroid...

Comment: Sorry for the answer my mistake. So someone can help me? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the [Java ISO Image Creator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jiic/)? It provides a Java API for doing just that.

Comment: I will try it. But work on Android?  Thankyou

Comment: Finally I was able to create an img with dd command and mount it with losetup and mount. But now I want to mount it on virtual usb. I explain: what I want is to show the content of this image on pc when I plug the usb cable to the android phone. Now the phone start the mtp protocol but I don't want it I want my phone is recognize as ums but not all my sdcard file will be showed but only the content of my .img  thankyou so much

Comment: Now, this sounds like a **different question**. Please don't append questions to questions.

Comment: Ok sorry, I open a new question. thankyou

Comment: link is not available, can you please update it?

Comment: @Ravi Done, though it would seem the project is now discontinued.

Comment: @matiash but how can i implement it? as i m not able to open website, can you share any implementation for this?